# Reconfigure Homestead vagrant box after issue

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have windows 10 and there was issues. Issue was with vagrant-vbox and network adapters, vbox or vagrant create about 10 Virtual network adapters. I delete them all and there was one for my homestead machine. Now homestead wont' up. And after trying to start VM with homestead through GUI of VBox I get this error.

```
Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
```

I try to use **vagrant reload --provision** but this have no effect.

Is it possible to fix my issue without reinstall of homestead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=64029)

> - open Virtual Box
> - --> Go to Device Manager
> - --> Network adapters
> - --> Uninstall network adapter (on which setting Bridged adapter is not working)
> - --> Click on Scan for harware changes
> - --> Restart PC
> - --> after restart go to Device Manager
> - --> Network adapters
> - --> uninstalled network adapter will be marked with "!", again uninstall this network adapter
> - --> Click on Scan for harware changes
> - now network adapter will be installed and restart will not be required. It is all, test Bridged adapter in VirtualBox ...